# Is it possible to call a method defined on the razor component in Razor pages?

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a razor page in my project. This page catches encrypted Ids and sends to a razor component which is working dynamically as parameters. The problem is that one of the methods of the razor components must be called from the razor page. Is it possible or is there any other way to resolve the issue?

I'm tried to create a service for the methods of the component. But I was not able to pass the parameters in the service to the component and control the right divisions at the right time with two way binding.

Comment: You need to be more specific and show some code, preferably some form of minimal reproducible example - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Without that, your question is likely to get closed as: Needing more clarity and focus.

Comment: If you're simply trying to call a method on a component from the hosting page, you just need to add an `@ref` attribute on the component and then call the public method using that reference. As previously mentioned, though, it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do here without more details.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below example helps. We pass **encryptedIds** to the ComponentTwo component method in this example.

```cshtml
<ComponentTwo @ref="_component" />

<Button Color="ButtonColor.Danger" @onclick="SendEncryptedIds"> Send </Button>

@code {
    private ComponentTwo _component;

    private async Task SendEncryptedIds()
    {
        var encryptedtIds = .... get the ids ....
        await _component.SendDataAsync(encryptedtIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I need a communication between two components, this example may very useful for me. But my page which is sending request to the component is a razor page. That's why I can not use this way.